# Synchronization of three streams in a specific queue with Mutex

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

there is a slight problem with threads, please tell me how to solve it or at least in which direction to look for, looking for a long time, but so far without success ... Here's the problem: there are 3 threads, they can run in any order (321;213;123...). In whatever order flows we would not run, they need to work out in the order 1,2,3. For this purpose, use thread synchronization with ONE mutex. In advance thank you.

Comment: Is this homework?  No experienced developer would actually consider using anything like this in a real app or apply any silly restrictions like 'use thread synchronization with ONE mutex'.

Comment: Yes, tou are right, I don't know how to do it :(
Please, take me some advice

Answer (score 1):

use mutex to protect a global integer, iThread.  Init iThread to 1.
create threads, pass in an id for each thread: 1,2,3.

In thread proc, lock mutex to check iThread.  If iThread != thread id, then wait on condition.

if iThread = thread id: unlock mutex, execute work in threadproc; at end of thread proc: lock mutex, ++iThread, and signal condition, unlock mutex.

something like that.  There are a million other ways.